# Get JavaScript local date from Moment JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, heroku, momentjs

Consider the code :

```
 let now = moment();
 console.log(now.format());  // 2019-11-25T20:23:50+02:00
 console.log(now.toDate());  // 2019-11-25T18:23:50.916Z
```

This is the output on my local machine , and when I check the app on Heroku 
it gives the same values , even though I changed the TZ like this :

> heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Jerusalem"

How can I get a JavaScript Date (**Not a String !**) object of my localtime  , meaning `2019-11-25T20:23:50` ?

Comment: Date objects don't have a timezone, they are UTC. The methods that produce local values (*toString*, *getHours*, *getMinutes*, etc.) use the system timezone offset and settings.

Comment: The first string is UTC+2, which is the current Jerusalem offset. The second string is UTC+0 (or plain UTC). They both show the same instant in time, just with different offsets as the console is using a different *toString* method for each object. 2019-11-25T20:23:50 doesn't have an offset, so it will be treated as local and represents a different instant in time in every place with a different local offset.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through your code example:

> ```
> let now = moment();
> ```

You create a `Moment` object.  You don't pass any parameters, so it is initialized using the current timestamp (as if you called `Date.now()`) and set to "local mode".

> ```
> console.log(now.format());  // 2019-11-25T20:23:50+02:00
> ```

By calling `format`, you ask the `Moment` object to produce a `String`.  Since it's in local mode, the offset that applies to that moment in time for the local time zone is emitted in the result, and the wall time shown in the result is adjusted for that offset.  In this case, the local time is two hours ahead of UTC.  You then pass that string to `console.log`, which emits it to the console.

> ```
> console.log(now.toDate());  // 2019-11-25T18:23:50.916Z
> ```

By calling `toDate`, you ask the `Moment` object to create a `Date` object.  The "mode" of the moment object is no longer relevant because `Date` objects don't track anything other than a timestamp.  Thus, the timestamp within the `Moment` object becomes the timestamp for the resulting `Date` object.  Since you derived the `Moment` object from the current time, the result is the same as if you just called `new Date()` to begin with.

You then pass the string to `console.log` - except one can't just log an object, so it first has to convert it to *something* so you can see it.  Here's the interesting part: ***There is no spec for this behavior.***  Implementations of ECMAScript can do whatever they like in this regard.  Some implementations, like in your example, will call `.toISOString()` and log the result.  Since `.toISOString()` displays the result in UTC, the result of logging a `Date` object is also shown in UTC.  But other implementations will call `.toString()` on the `Date` object and log that, the result being in *local* time.  It's entirely possible some future implementation could show the result in some graphical or interactive output.  The point being, you can't rely on the behavior of `console.log(Date)` to be consistent.

No amount of changing your time zone settings will change this result.  The `Date` object is inherently UTC-based, your output is also UTC-based, and UTC is the same over the whole planet (by design).

If you want the time zone reflected in the string output, you must use a function that produces a string with respect to local time.  As you showed, you'll get that with `.format()` on a `Moment` object in local mode.  You can also get one from calling `.toString()` on a `Date` object (but the resulting string is not in the same ISO 8601 format).

Answer (score 0):

i would try,

```
moment().local().toDate()
```

but if you are planning to save date into db it's good practice to save time in UTC format for easier global conversion.

If you want to work timezones you may require also moment timezone package -  https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

```
npm install moment-timezone
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not sure `moment().local().toDate()` produces a different result to `new Date()`.

Comment: I do need to save dates & times to DB , that's the problem.I need to manipulate dates and times and we need to work under local time.Why do you thing that it's better to save the time under UTC ?